# how to get rid hidden diagonal text in the pdf file

Tags: pdf

***please note that, there are similar questions to this. but none came up with screen shots nor a pdf sample***

i have come up with a very weird pdf page. when i was testing some text split with python, i observed some extra text on the document.

here is the single page pdf file: https://smallpdf.com/file#s=c1e3e9a1-76ea-478b-a9d2-78eb93f4e1c6

to check the problem deeper, went for a manual check. if "55074" is searched on this file, some invisible regions got detected. below you will see 5 yellow match regions, where the search string is detected

[image]

and more strangely i'm able to select some of these regions diagonally (blue regions are my selection when hold left mouse and move)

[image]

i have never seen such a pdf file before. is there a way to get rid of these kind of hidden regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not easily without a full trace, or a full replacement of the OCR.

They seem to be OCR artefacts added and combined with watermarking?

Here I moved the image out of the way and we see much of the selection could potentially be deleted, however if we did not filter out just the diagonally ones, there could be collateral damage.
These artefacts include sections such as
"cover
images
&
additional
information,
updated
daily,
subscribe
to
[www.booksinprint.com](http://www.booksinprint.com).
Titles "

However that last word `Titles "` does not show up in a search, it is off the page at 90 degrees! so aligned with where the index tab should be

Thus not simply a case of delete large chunks., it could need some finesse.

[image]

Without sight of other pages it is hard to guess if there is some common facet that would identify what is surplus to requirement.
[image]

One solution may be to export just the text as laid out and PDFtoText in such cases may have an option to ignore diagonal text. Then it can be spell checked and re-used as a base for a better underlay behind the image. Or for small cases, I might use an editor such as shown to remove surplus rogue data by hand.

**However in large cases with good images, it may be easier to replace the OCR across all pages after removing the rogue OCR.**

Comment: ty for the great answer. i had found that extra text with some luck. i think i can find those hidden with some specialized tools like you use. those images you sent really opened new ideas. now installing adobe acrobat trial for a deeper check

Comment: update: i did OCR with the adobe, and now all seems good. no more diagonal extra hidden text.
could you please add a small comment, suggesting to do the OCR again. so that i can mark your answer as solution?